# Inserting into a table returns "SyntaxException: line 4:0 no viable alternative at input ')' (....movies( id, videos,[)]...)"

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to define some types and use it creating a table like below:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS movie WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3};
    
CREATE TYPE movie.comment (ratings LIST<BOOLEAN>,);
    
CREATE TYPE movie.videos (comments LIST<FROZEN<comment>>);
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movie.movies (videos LIST<FROZEN<videos>>,);
```

And they will be created successfully. But when I try to `INSERT` some variables into the table like following, I get the below error:

```
INSERT INTO movie.movies(
  id,
  videos,
)values(
  'id', 
  [{
    comments: 
        [true, false,false]
  }]
);
```

ERROR:

```
SyntaxException: line 4:0 no viable alternative at input ')' (....movies(  id,  videos,[)]...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors here:

- you have `,` after `videos` and before `)` - remove it
- your `movie.movies` table definition doesn't have `id` column
- you don't have primary key defined for the table

But really, I don't see the definition of `videos LIST<FROZEN<videos>>` as  a good practice - instead, implement each video as a separate row.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also please let me know why defining `videos` like above isn't a good practice?

Comment: `list` isn't the best type for keeping the data. you need to read the whole column even if you need just one video, etc. You can look for best practices in one of this documents: https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/bestPractices.html (there is a separate section on schema analysis)

Comment: I have posted a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75845607/typeerror-type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listmoviesvideo

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors in the CQL statements you posted, particularly for the schema which I think you've fixed because they would fail to execute otherwise.

In any case, the `INSERT` statement failed because of the error on the fourth line as the error message indicates:

```
SyntaxException: line 4:0 ...
```

which specifically is `)values(`.

The CQL parser was not expecting the closing parenthesis (`no viable alternative at input ')'`) because line number 3 has a comma (`,`) at the end of it (`videos,`).

The correct format for the CQL statement is:

```
INSERT INTO movie.movies (id, videos) VALUES (...)
```

We recommend you use this format as a template for your statements to make it easier to pick up on errors.

As a side note, the answer to the question you didn't ask is that we don't recommend using CQL collection types like `list` for data that can grow unbounded. We also recommend that you avoid user-defined types (UDTs) due to the level of complexity they add to your application particularly since you are new to Cassandra.

You should use generic column types whenever possible instead. For example, it would make more sense to store comments in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE comments_by_movie_title (
    movie_title text,
    comment_id text,
    comment text,
    rating boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY (movie_title, comment_id)
)
```

This way, you can retrieve all the comments for a movie with:

```
SELECT comment, rating FROM comments_by_movie_title
  WHERE movie_title = ?
```

Modelling your data in this manner avoids (1) having to deal with the complexity of CQL collections and UDTs, and (2) getting better performance since the table is optimised for reads. Cheers!